# Split String between character and number into an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

I have a string that looks like this:

```
$data1 = "W97";
$data2 = "RP100";
$data3 = "MAL89";
$data4 = "UNIQ95";
```

The string will contain a char first then it will contain a number, i want to split the between the character and number into array, for example :

```
print_r($this->splitString($data1)); //array([0]=>'W',[1]=>97)
print_r($this->splitString($data2)); //array([0]=>'RP',[1]=>100)
print_r($this->splitString($data3)); //array([0]=>'MAL',[1]=>89)
print_r($this->splitString($data4)); //array([0]=>'UNIQ',[1]=>95)

function splitString($string){
  $result = array();
  //???
  return $result;
}
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is only ever one 'character' part, followed by one number part, this regexp will match them both separately:

```
/^([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)$/
```

Used in `preg_match()`, this gives the following result:

```
$regexp = '/^([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)$/';
$string = 'ABC1234';
$matches = [];

preg_match($regexp, $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

// Output:
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(7) "ABC1234"
  [1] =>
  string(3) "ABC"
  [2] =>
  string(4) "1234"
}
```

Just unset (or ignore) the first index, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

use this method this will work for you.

```
$data1      = "W2020";
$data2      = "AB2020";
$data3      = "ZXCV2020";

print_r(splitString($data3));

function splitString($string){
    $alpha_string = '';
    $num_string = '';
    $array2 = str_split( $string );

    foreach($array2 as $value){
        if(is_numeric($value))
            $num_string .= $value;
         else
            $alpha_string .= $value;
    }
    $data_array = array($alpha_string, $num_string);

    return $data_array;
}
```

that's it. This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use lookaround:

```
$data1 = "W97";
$data2 = "RP100";
$data3 = "MAL89";
$data4 = "UNIQ95";


print_r(splitString($data1)); //array([0]=>'W',[1]=>97)
print_r(splitString($data2)); //array([0]=>'RP',[1]=>100)
print_r(splitString($data3)); //array([0]=>'MAL',[1]=>89)
print_r(splitString($data4)); //array([0]=>'UNIQ',[1]=>95)

function splitString($string){
  $result = array();
  $result = preg_split('/(?<=[A-Z])(?=\d)/', $string);
  return $result;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => W
    [1] => 97
)
Array
(
    [0] => RP
    [1] => 100
)
Array
(
    [0] => MAL
    [1] => 89
)
Array
(
    [0] => UNIQ
    [1] => 95
)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=[A-Z])      # positive lookbehind, make sure we have a capital letter before the current position
(?=\d)          # positive lookahead, make sure we have a digit after the current position
```

- Further reading: [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)